# Skipping a line after an array element is printed

Tags: javascript

I am trying to print out my array vertically. So once one of the items is listed in the array, include a skipped line before the next element is printed.

My code looks like the following. It is printing out, however it's horizontal and not appealing

```
 request.execute(function(resp) {
              for (var x = 0; x < resp.items.length; x++){  
                var str = resp.items[x].title;
                var result = str.link(resp.items[x].alternateLink);
                linkPush.push(result);
              }
                  document.getElementById("container9").innerHTML = linkPush;

          });
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
document.getElementById("container9").innerHTML = linkPush.join('<br/>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap anchors with divs

```
request.execute(function(resp) {
              for (var x = 0; x < resp.items.length; x++){  
                var str = resp.items[x].title;
                var result = str.link(resp.items[x].alternateLink);
                linkPush.push('<div>', result, ',</div>');
              }
                  document.getElementById("container9").innerHTML = linkPush.join('');

          });
```

Comment: @torazaburo Take a guess.